# Is there a way to make tags in lit-html templates dynamic?

Tags: lit-element, lit, lit-html

Question is pretty much self-explanatory.

Example:

```
function generateTemplate(tag) {
  return html`
    <${tag}
      .some-prop=${1}
    >
      ...
    </${tag}>
  `;
}
```

Comment: Related issues in lit-html repo: https://github.com/Polymer/lit-html/issues/217

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic tags for lit-html not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59666518/dynamic-tags-for-lit-html-not-possible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't one way to do specifically what you mention here, but there are two approaches that can get you somewhat close:

- Conditional rendering

```js
const template = tag => { 
  if (tag === 'custom-component') {
    return html`<custom-component></custom-component>`;
  } else if (tag === 'other-component') {
    return html`...`;
  } else {
    return html`<some-default></some-default>`;
  }
};
```

- Using the [unsafe html directive](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference#unsafehtml)

```js
import {unsafeHTML} from 'lit-html/directives/unsafe-html.js';
const template = unsafeContent => {
  // bear in mind that this should only be done after sanitizing the content
  return html`${unsafeHTML(unsafeContent)}`;
};
template('<my-component>Some content</my-component>');
```

Comment: Yeah, was already doing the same thing as conditional rendering via switch cases but there's just too many and it's basically the same properties for each anyway. Could probably work with the `unsafeHTML` directive but need to sanitize the items set to the props like you said. Hmm.