# Dynamic tags for lit-html not possible?

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element, lit-element, lit-html

Can anyone tell me why I cannot use variables within lit-html's `html` method?

```
const h1 = 'h1';
return html`
  <${h1} class="a-heading ${classes}">
    <slot></slot>
  </${h1}>
`;
```

If I replace `${h1}` with `h1` that works without problems.

Comment: ask them! https://github.com/polymer/lit-html/issues

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to make tags in lit-html templates dynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59259400/is-there-a-way-to-make-tags-in-lit-html-templates-dynamic)

Comment: @AlanDávalos At first I thought 'yes', because it says this is not possible. But a working colleague just helped me out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For everyone interested in my solution: Use `unsafeHTML` if you can (you should not do that if you wrap any input fields within).

```
    import { unsafeHTML } from 'lit-html/directives/unsafe-html';
   
     // ...

    const template = `
      <h${this.rank} class="a-heading">
        <slot></slot>
      </h${this.rank}>
    `;

    return html`
      ${unsafeHTML(template)}
    `;
```

Comment: This is no longer recommended approach - use `literal` or `unsafeStatic` as shown in the other answer.

Answer (score 12):

It's 2022 and the solution exists (from the end of 2020 - [Issue](https://github.com/lit/lit/issues/78)).

Now you can use something from https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#static-expressions

1. For string literals, that you have control of, use `literal` template.

   *You must import special version of `html` and use the `literal` template.*

```
import {html, literal} from 'lit/static-html.js';

@customElement('my-button')
class MyButton extends LitElement {
  tag = literal`button`;
  activeAttribute = literal`active`;
  @property() caption = 'Hello static';
  @property({type: Boolean}) active = false;

  render() {
    return html`
      <${this.tag} ${this.activeAttribute}?=${this.active}>
        <p>${this.caption}</p>
      </${this.tag}>`;
  }
}
```

and then

```
@customElement('my-anchor')
class MyAnchor extends MyButton {
  tag = literal`a`;
}
```

2. For something, that you cannot decorate using the `literal`, you can use `unsafeStatic`.

   *Again, you must import special version of `html` and then use `unsafeStatic` function.*

```
import {html, unsafeStatic} from 'lit/static-html.js';

@customElement('my-button')
class MyButton extends LitElement {
  @property() caption = 'Hello static';
  @property({type: Boolean}) active = false;

  render() {
    // These strings MUST be trusted, otherwise this is an XSS vulnerability
    const tag = getTagName();
    const activeAttribute = getActiveAttribute();
    return html`
      <${unsafeStatic(tag)} ${unsafeStatic(activeAttribute)}?=${this.active}>
        <p>${this.caption}</p>
      </${unsafeStatic(tag)}>`;
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't verify that this works, but this looks like the thing I wanted back then! Thanks for posting this.

Comment: Thank you.
It is working, I am using it. But it took me way too long until I find out about this feature. I think some people like me, who stumble across this question, will find this useful.

Comment: But this solution doesn't allow me add in other template with `html`, is there a workaround?

Comment: Using import {html} from 'lit/static-html.js'; instead  
import { html } from "lit"; helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

**Update: Thanks @Gh61 for a current answer!**

**This answer is no longer correct. lit-html 2.0+ has a static template function that accepts bindings in any position**

The reason `lit-html` doesn't allow for dynamic tag names is that lit-html works by replacing the expressions with special markers and then creating an HTML `<template>` element with the result.

The key, and slightly subtle, part here is that it does *not* use the values to create the template. They are interpolated into the template *after* the template is cloned, which is after the HTML has ben parsed. There's no way to go into a tree of DOM and change the tag name of one element. We'd have to remove the element, replace it, set up any bindings, and move any children into the new element. This would be very expensive.

We do have plans to support static bindings (once we can drop support for older Edge browsers that don't implement template literals quite correctly) which are interpolated *before* creating the HTML `<template>`, which would allow for using expressions for tag names. Static bindings would not be updatable with new data however - the value at template creation time is the only value used.

Comment: Consider updating (or deleting) the answer in favor of current `literal` and `unsafeStatic` solutions.