# How to render html tag inside Template literals (LitElement)?

Tags: javascript, html, lit-element, template-literals

I want Template literals with foo-nr1, foo-nr2 ... and use them as HTML Tag.

```
render(
        html `<foo-nrX></foo-nrX>`,
        document.querySelector('#bigfoo')
      );
```

Because X is a placeholder, I tried everything like this:

```
        html `<${fooplaceholder}></${fooplaceholder}>`,
```

or this from similar q/a here:

```
const getHTML = message => unescape(message).replace('\\', '');
const setHTML = escape('<' + foo-nrX + '></' + foo-nrX + '>');

        html `${getHTML(setHTML)}`,
```

However, best results are:
`"<foo-nrX></foo-nrX>"`

instead of:
`<foo-nrX></foo-nrX>`

So he doesnt parse it as HTML Tag, instead it shows up as String into the website.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic tags for lit-html not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59666518/dynamic-tags-for-lit-html-not-possible)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by myself:

```
import {unsafeHTML} from 'lit-html/directives/unsafe-html.js';

const foo = '<' + fooNrX + '></' + fooNrX + '>';

render(
        html `${unsafeHTML(foo)}`,
        document.querySelector('#bigfoo')
      );
```