# Render JSON to HTML without dynamic tags

Tags: lit-html, lit

Let's say I have a data structure like this

```json
[{tag: 'h1', text:'lorem ipsum', attrs:{data-foo: 'bar'}},
 {tag: 'blockquote', text:'dolor sit'},
 {tag: 'p', text:'atmet'}]
```

that I want to render into HTML:

```html
<h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
<blockquote>dolor sit</blockquote>
<p>amet</p>
```

Using vanilla JS, `el=document.createElement(entry.tag), el.innerText=entry.text`. I could add the data attribute if one exists and use the element object, e.g. to conditionally add an event listener to only the heading.

I understand that `lit-html` [does not support dynamic tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59833334/4247704). I also don't see how the attribute could be set or event listeners could be conditionally attached except like `@click=${condition ? listener : null}` but that looks too weird for being advisable.

Is there a way to use `lit-html` more elegantly?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic tags for lit-html not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59666518/dynamic-tags-for-lit-html-not-possible)

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to use [static expressions](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#static-expressions) to generate a template from a data structure like you're proposing.

For example

```js
import {html, unsafeStatic} from 'lit/static-html.js';

html`<${unsafeStatic(entry.tag)}>${entry.text}</${unsafeStatic(entry.tag)}>`;
```

Or you could construct the entire HTML string and render it with the [`unsafeHTML`](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/directives/#unsafehtml) directive.

Of course they come with performance and security caveats.

For conditionally adding attributes, if the condition is based on whether the value to be placed is defined, you can use the [`ifDefined`](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/directives/#ifdefined) directive.